# Wireless USB adapter with OS X support?

Tags: macos, usb, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I haven't been able to locate any other wireless USB adapters with OS X support.

It should rather be able to handle 108 Mbit/s or higher.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** As I'm not a Mac user, I totally mixed up what Airport devices do. Now I realize what an Airport Express device does, thanks to [The Devil Tesla](https://superuser.com/questions/27031/wireless-usb-adapter-with-os-x-support-besides-airport-express/27503#27503), so I edited my question.

I prefer an USB adapter for the portability's sake, even though an access point would do the job.

Comment: Airport Express isn't a wireless USB adaptor, but an access point with a USB port. Do you mean a plugin USB device to allow a non wireless enabled machine to use wireless?

Comment: Yes, I meant a plugin USB device. Sorry about the confusion, as I 'm not familiar with what the Mac devices are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wireless USB adaptors, check this list of adaptors that use the [Ralink RT2500 chipset](http://ralink.rapla.net/)
(USB column) and install the appropriate [Ralink drivers](http://www.ralinktech.com/ralink/Home/Support/Macintosh.html) for Mac OS X.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, thanks! Most products don't have information on their web pages about which chipset is used, but that's something for me to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of Airport Express as a router, think of it as a router that is also a print server. I do not know of any routers other than the Apple ones that combine both functions (it's a shame really). But yea, you are going to have to find first a router and then a print server that can work over OS X, and I believe that the major router makers (being Belkan, Linksys, and D-Link) make both.

Answer (score 1):

Get drivers from Realtek

http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=1&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=4

Answer (score 1):

I found a Wireless-N USB adapter from Panda Wireless on Amazon.
It used a ralink chipset and comes with drivers for Mac OS X.
I may work for you.